# Print large integer as exponential function

Tags: c, printf, gmp

I would like to print a huge integer in exponential form. Something like

```
Value 123456789012 as exp is 1.2345*10^12.
```

Is there any gmp_printf format to handle this or should I calculate it first with some mpz_get_exp function?

```
mpz_t integer;
mpz_t exponent;
mpf_t top;

mpz_inits(integer, exponent, null);
mpf_init(top);

mpz_set_str(integer, "123456789012", 10);

???

gmp_printf("Value %Zd as exp is %.4Ff*10^%Zd",
           integer, top, exonent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%Fe` or `%FE` format specifier expects an object of `mpf_t` type. Hence, you would need to create temporary variable just for `gmp_printf()`. For instance:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gmp.h>

int main(void)
{
    mpz_t integer;

    mpz_init_set_str(integer, "123456789012", 10);
    /* Print integer's value in scientific notation */
    {
        mpf_t tmp_float;
        mpf_init(tmp_float);
        mpf_set_z(tmp_float, integer);
        gmp_printf("%.4FE\n", tmp_float);
        mpf_clear(tmp_float);
    }
    mpz_clear(integer);
    return 0;
}
```

Resulting into:

```
1.2346E+11
```

Alernatively you could export it into POD `double` by [`mpz_get_d`](https://gmplib.org/manual/Converting-Integers.html#Converting-Integers) and print it by ordinary `printf()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gmp.h>

int main(void)
{
    mpz_t integer;

    mpz_init_set_str(integer, "123456789012", 10);
    printf("%.4E\n", mpz_get_d(integer));

    mpz_clear(integer);
    return 0;
}
```

I would preffer second approach is it looks much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

The [gmplib](https://gmplib.org/manual/Formatted-Output-Strings.html) documentation seems to indicate that the `%e` or `%E` printf options should work just fine. These print in scientific notation.

`gmp_printf("%e", integer);`